# Puppet roles/profiles, role with multiple instances of profile - how do parameters work?

Tags: puppet

I am just learning Puppet (we have Puppet Enterprise locally).  I am trying to understand the "*roles and profiles*" pattern.  Please pardon any nomenclature slip ups.

How do I create a role with multiple instances of a profile, where the profile instances differ only by parameter?  I'm guessing Hiera fits into this somewhere but I'm not exactly sure how.

For example:

*Puppetfile:*

```
mod 'puppetlabs-apache', '2.3.0'
```

*apache.pp profile*

```
class profile::apache (
    String $port = '80',
) {

  class { 'apache':
    listen => $port,
  }

}
```

*twoapaches.pp role*

```
class role::twoapaches {
  include profile::apache
  include profile::apache
}
```

I want an instance of the twoapaches role to have an apache at ports 90 and 100 - how do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually can't use classes like that in Puppet; a class can only be declared once-per-node.

You probably need some of the [defined types](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/lang_defined_types.html) in the [puppetlabs/apache](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-apache) module. Defined types are used when you need to declare a user-defined "resource" more than once on a single node.

E.g. profile might be:

```
class profile::two_vhosts {
  apache::vhost { 'ip1.example.com':
    ip      => ['127.0.0.1','169.254.1.1'],
    port    => '80',
    docroot => '/var/www/ip',
  }
  apache::vhost { 'ip2.example.com':
    ip      => ['127.0.0.1'],
    port    => '8080',
    docroot => '/var/www/ip',
  }
}
```

And the role might be:

```
class role::two_vhosts {
  include profile::two_vhosts
  include profile::other_stuff
  ...
}
```

If you needed to then pass the ports in, you might have:

```
class profile::two_vhosts (
  String $ip1_port,
  String $ip2_port, 
) {
  apache::vhost { 'ip1.example.com':
    ip      => ['127.0.0.1','169.254.1.1'],
    port    => $ip1_port,
    docroot => '/var/www/ip',
  }
  apache::vhost { 'ip2.example.com':
    ip      => ['127.0.0.1'],
    port    => $ip2_port,
    docroot => '/var/www/ip',
  }
}
```

You *could* then have your role as:

```
class role::two_vhosts {
  class { 'profile::two_vhosts':
    ip1_port => '80',
    ip2_port => '8080',
  } 
  include profile::other_stuff
  ...
}
```

But in practice people use the Automatic Parameter Lookup feature here in conjunction with Hiera ([ref](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/4.10/hiera_automatic.html)).

Comment: I see. So if I wanted to pass the ports into "profile::two_vhosts" as parameters.  Could I do that?

Comment: In my opinion the role would be named something different, but most of roles/profiles is opinion and overall really good demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Hiera also for the parameters. This way you can easily change ports if needed and you comply with the rule of no putting [classes inside the roles](https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2017.1/r_n_p_full_example.html):

```
class role::two_vhosts {
  include profile::two_vhosts
  include profile::other_stuff
  ...
}
```

Hiera configuration when including the role would be something like this:

```
profile::two_vhosts::ip1_port: '80'
profile::two_vhosts::ip2_port: '8080'
```